# Magento automatic send email payment pending

Tags: magento, mailing

I am currently building a magento online store and I am 
using the Payone/Wirecard module for the payment. 
Is it possible to send an email to a customer if 
the order status "Payment pending"?

Comment: a payment reminder e-mail after x days or something else?

Comment: Yeah. After a couple of minutes (30-60).

Comment: it's possible but this functionality is not included. you could implement this with an own module or buy a commercial module (just google "magento payment reminder"). in both cases you need the magento cron job as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have an plugin suggestion?

Comment: no, just google: just google "magento payment reminder" because i don't know exactly what you need